# Custom Weighted Resampling

Tags: mlr

How can I create a custom weighted ResampleInstance in mlr? It is possible to specify weights in the train function or in a task description. I need to create custom weights for a time series for every resampling instance.

Comment: You can assign custom weights, see the rebalancing sections of the [cost sensitive classification tutorial page](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/cost_sensitive_classif.html). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the reference Lars. That section does however show only `makeWeightedClassesWrapper` for imbalanced class problems. The tutorial mentions "observation weights", but I think it is meant as class weight for that wrapper. I could create as many classes as I have observations, but that would still not get me where I need. The cleanest solutions would be to write a custom resampling functions for my purpose. I am aware of the `forecasting` extenstion for mlr3, but I would need something different. Would you suggest to write the extension for mlr or mlr3?

Comment: Ah, right. I don't think what you're looking for is supported in mlr at the moment then. All new development is happening for mlr3 now.

Comment: I have created a pull request for this: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/pull/239